# isEqualToString Combinations

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, combinations

I have multiple strings combinations that I want my isEqualtoString to find automatically.
Right now, I have all combinations manually searched.

```
if([aString isEqualToString:@"xyz"] || [aString isEqualToString:@"zxy"] || [aString isEqualToString:@"yzx"] || [aString isEqualToString:@"xzy"] etc...){}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to know if any of them match, you can put all your candidates (xyz, zxy, ...) in an `NSArray` and call `containsObject:aString` on the array. Use `indexOfObject:aString` if you need to know which string was matched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seems much simpler, and I like simple.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a NSString category that does the job:

```
@interface NSString (isEqualToAnyStringAddition)
- (BOOL)isEqualToAnyString:(NSString *)firstString, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
@end

@implementation NSString (isEqualToAnyStringAddition)

- (BOOL)isEqualToAnyString:(NSString *)firstString, ...
{
    if([self isEqualToString:firstString])
        return YES;


    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, firstString);

    NSString *string;

    while((string = va_arg(arguments, NSString *)))
    {
        if([self isEqualToString:string])
        {
            va_end(arguments);
            return YES;
        }
    }

    va_end(arguments);
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If I ever become a hardcore dev and want to spiff up my code looks then I'll use this ^_^. Meanwhile, I think that containsObject would work easier..